# Failed to update driver: "pk-client-error-quark:Failed to obtain authentication(303)"

Tags: nvidia, additional-drivers

I am new to Linux and I am using Ubuntu. I was use x.org drivers and I want to change to Nvidia. When I get into **Software & Updates** and in **Additional Drivers** try to change x.org to nvidia I get an error:

> pk-client-error-quark:Failed to obtain authentication(303)

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: First of all make sure your system is fully updated: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: 20.04 LTS is my ubuntu version

Comment: @ChanganAuto Updating didn't work.

Comment: *Updating didn't work*... So, did the update procedure produced any error or didn't but the problem persisted when trying to install the Nvidia driver? Also, are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I don't use proxy. when I run code you gave I noticed it's not completed correctly so(give some problem I was find it not important) I run code seperatly. 'sudo apt update' give some problem after download something but its complete. but sudo apt full-upgrade is complete too. after I rebooted computer and problem is persisted when downloading Nvidia driver.

Comment: I have the problem that the Ubuntu 22.04 open-source driver won't connect to the Internet. When I tried to select the Broadcom driver in Software & Updates,  I just got this message. It is impossible to use `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` because I can't access the Internet.

Answer (score 10):

I had the exact same error report following a stuck update. To release the stuck update, I ran `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and then an autoremove.

After restarting, my screen configuration was totally trashed and the system was using the open-source non-proprietary driver (and very unstable, and slow). I tried to install the nvidia driver and received this message.

I then ran the driver installation from the command line using the following steps:

1. identify available/appropriate drivers with this command:
   `ubuntu-drivers devices`
2. choose the one marked "recommended"
3. install it using the command:
   `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-XXX`
   (replace XXX with the driver id number you want)
4. reboot:
   `sudo reboot`

After this, my system came back properly.

HTH

Comment: somehow, after a startup, my second screen has gone, and i did the 3rd one (sudo apt install nvidia-driver-XXX), that was solved my situation.

Comment: I had `nvidia-driver-525` installed. I just run the command to install it again and it worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 and I got the same error in "Additional Drivers". I've been flipping back and forth between different Nvidia drivers and have multiple video cards. I went into the shell and did "sudo apt autoremove" and "sudo apt install nvidia-driver-495" and the driver installed with no issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1199640)

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to 22.10, then choosing driver 25 (recommended) in Software & updates solved my Nvidia installations issues for Nvidia RTX3080ti.